# vaadin 8 FilesystemContainer alternative

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin8

I used FilesystemContainer in a Vaadin 7 application to populate the contents of a com.vaadin.ui.Tree for viewing and selecting files on the server.

```
tree.setContainerDataSource (new FilesystemContainer (new File ("o: \\")));
```

However, when migrating this application to Vaadin 8 I did not find an alternative to the FilesystemContainer. Could anyone tell me which way would be the best?

Comment: Could you explain why did you revert previous changes? Now you have `vaidim` instead of `Vaadin` and your post begs to be edited again.

Comment: There was indeed a need to correct the word vaidim by vaadin, but its editing had too many unnecessary corrections elsewhere in the text. If his edition had corrected the essentials it would have been approved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is missing feature in Vaadin 8 and subsequent versions, but thanks for the idea. It is not very complex task to implement `FilesystemDataProvider` in Vaadin 8, thus I made one:

https://vaadin.com/directory/component/filesystem-dataprovider-add-on

The source code and demo application are in GitHub, see demo application how to use:

https://github.com/TatuLund/FilesystemDataProvider/blob/master/filesystemdataprovider-demo/src/main/java/org/vaadin/filesystemdataprovider/demo/DemoUI.java

There is version also for the new Vaadin versions like Vaadin 14 as well. In Vaadin 14 version there is FTP variant too.